# Issues flattening row from a table python

Tags: arcpy, query, python-script-tool

I'm trying to merge duplicates rows using this Python script. After I run the script I get this error and the output just drop the duplicates and it doesn't merge any duplicate row. I want to create a one to many relationship where the FID carries all its attributes in one row. I have look at other solutions. They recommended using Pivot tool but that doesn't solve the duplicate issues.

```
#MERGE ROW USING CURSOR SEARCH
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:dummy' # Replace correct geodatabase path
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Make a copy of the original feature class/ table
arcpy.Copy_management('attribPivot_4', 'attribPivot_4_flatten')

# Collapse the output feature class
FIDList = []
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('attribPivot_4_flatten', ['FID']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in FIDList:
            cursor.deleteRow()
        else:
            FIDList.append(row[0])

for FID in FIDList:
    #Syntax SearchCursor (in_table, field_names, {where_clause}, {spatial_reference}, {explode_to_points}, {sql_clause})
    # Compile the values in the original feature class
    attList = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('attribPivot_4', ['PERCENTAGE', 'C5-3', 'M1-4', 'M1-4/R6A', 'M1-4/R6B', 'M1-4/RA7', 'M1-5/R10', 'M1-5/R7-3', 'M1-5/R9', 'M1-6/R10', 'PARK', 'R6A', 'R6B', 'R7A','R9'], "FID = " + str(FID)) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            for i in range(0,14):
                if row[i] != 0:
                    attList[i] = row[i]

    # Update the values in the collapse feature class
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('attribPivot_4_flatten', ['PERCENTAGE', 'C5-3', 'M1-4', 'M1-4/R6A', 'M1-4/R6B', 'M1-4/RA7', 'M1-5/R10', 'M1-5/R7-3', 'M1-5/R9', 'M1-6/R10', 'PARK', 'R6A', 'R6B', 'R7A','R9'], "FID = " + str(FID)) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            for i in range(0,14):
                row[i] = attList[i]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 24, in  RuntimeError: A column was specified that does
>   not exist.

Input

```
OBJ AREA_GEO  pk_area   FID PERCENTAGE  C5-3    M1-4    M1-4/R6A    M1-4/R6B    M1-4/R7A    M1-5/R10    M1-5/R7-3   M1-5/R9 M1-6/R10    PARK    R6A R6B R7A R9
172 1.113347    1.13    11  100.000009  0   1.113336    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42  0.456301    0.43    12  8.909635    0   0.040654    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
43  0.456301    0.43    12  91.09035    0   0   0   0.415642    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
178 1.210127    1.25    13  100.000018  0   1.210115    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
126 0.791088    0.81    14  99.999996   0   0.79108 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
171 1.09726     1.2     15  99.999977   0   1.097248    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
62  0.508533    0.47    16  99.999976   0   0   0   0.508528    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
66  0.513681    0.4     17  1.785656    0   0   0   0.009172    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
67  0.513681    0.4     17  98.214385   0   0   0.504504    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
149 0.876281    0.89    26  2.115458    0   0   0   0   0.018537    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
150 0.876281    0.89    26  31.28377    0   0   0.274131    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
151 0.876281    0.89    26  32.079764   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.281106    0   0   0
152 0.876281    0.89    26  34.520978   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.302498    0   0   0   0
```

This is what I'm trying to get, where all the percentages(the percentages can be in one column or in separate column I don't mind) and all the values for the other columns be in one row. Thus one ID with all its attributes in the same row.

```
OBJ AREA_GEO    pk_area FID PERCENTAGE  C5-3    M1-4    M1-4/R6A    M1-4/R6B    M1-4/R7A    M1-5/R10    M1-5/R7-3   M1-5/R9 M1-6/R10    PARK    R6A R6B R7A R9
172 1.113347    1.13    11  100.000009  0   1.113336    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42  0.456301    0.43    12  8.909635, 91.09035  0   0.040654    0   0.415642    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
178 1.210127    1.25    13  100.000018  0   1.210115    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
126 0.791088    0.81    14  99.999996   0   0.79108 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
171 1.09726     1.2     15  99.999977   0   1.097248    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
62  0.508533    0.47    16  99.999976   0   0   0   0.508528    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
66  0.513681    0.4     17  1.78, 98.2  0   0   0.504504    0.009172    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
149 0.876281    0.89    26  2.18, 31.27, 32.04, 34.58   0   0   0.274131    0   0.018537    0   0   0   0   0.302498    0.281106    0   0   0
```

Comment: Which ArcGIS version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 10.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no obvious reason why Pivot Table or Summary Statistics and then join should not work. But if you want to use Python, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a great module for this kind of task and is included in 10.4:

> pandas is an open source, BSD-licensed library providing
>   high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools
>   for the Python programming language.

Code will output a csv which you can join back to your data (after deleting duplicates on FID column). If this is not what you want i will delete my answer.

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\dummy.gdb'
output = r'C:\flat_csv.csv'

fieldlist = ['FID','PERCENTAGE','C5-3','M1-4','M1-4/R6A','M1-4/R6B','M1-4/R7A','M1-5/R10',
             'M1-5/R7-3','M1-5/R9','M1-6/R10','PARK','R6A','R6B','R7A','R9']

#Create a pandas dataframe using da.SearchCursor
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor('attribPivot_4', fieldlist), columns=fieldlist)

#Create dictionary of fieldnames and which function to use when grouping them. PERCENTAGE is comma-separated, rest summed
f = dict.fromkeys(fieldlist[2:], 'sum')
f[fieldlist[1]] = lambda x: ", ".join(x.astype(str))

#Groupby FID and export as csv
df.groupby('FID').agg(f).to_csv(path_or_buf=output, index=False)
```

Example of output:
[image]

Comment: Okay the answer seems to be going in the right direction but I get this error once I run the code.                                                              Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 801, in from_records
    first_row = next(data)
RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.

Comment: Okay but what about the other fields prior to FID (obj, area_geo, pk area) on my code I didn't state them, but I was able to keep them in my output. I added them to the fieldlist but I keep getting the error. fieldlist = ['OBJ','AREA_GEO','pk_area','FID','PERCENTAGE','C5-3', 'M1-4', 'M1-4/R6A', 'M1-4/R6B', 'M1-4/RA7', 'M1-5/R10',
             'M1-5/R7-3', 'M1-5/R9', 'M1-6/R10', 'PARK', 'R6A', 'R6B', 'R7A','R9']

Comment: Your answer is correct. After I fixed my table names I got this error.  line 21typeerror: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'     but I fixed adding this (after the word code) I don't know how to comment properly `code df2.drop("PERCENTAGE", axis=1, inplace=True)`